# Related Content issue

Tags: relationships

I have an issue displaying my related content to an entry.

To serve some context, I have a Channel called Projects, and I also have a Channel called Services.  In Projects I have a Relationship field called 'project_services' that pulls in content from the Services Channel.

Below is a gist of my code.

https://gist.github.com/NickToye/6045642

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which version of EECMS are you running?

Comment: I am using 2.6.1

Comment: Do you tried to remove the status parameter? This looks like a bug.

Comment: If I remove the status parameter it doesn't load the entry.

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe is a bug related to this. Please, try to remove the status parameter and set the status of the entry to open. Or set the status of the services to featured. It's just a test.

Comment: Ok, status is set to open, I have removed the status parameter, entry loads, but the related services are not displaying.

Comment: Thanks! Is it a multiple or a single relationship?

Comment: Setup for multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any issue in your code. It looks like a bug or a cache issue. Please, try to cleanup the [relationships cache](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/data/clear_cached_data_files.html).

In your place, I would use categories for services, instead of a channel: better performance and no cache issues.

Comment: Can you use multiple categories though?

Comment: I also have a 2nd related content called Platform.

Comment: In case of a portfolio, all this, platform, services, media and, even, clients, if its fields are simple... All this looks like categories to me. I can't see the point of create a full channel for something that is just a "quality" or a "property" of an entry.

Comment: So I can create multiple category groups for one channel?

Comment: Sure! For more than one!

Comment: Cool, I'm learning as I'm going here.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/NickToye/6045959

Its displaying all the categories, selected or not.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories

Comment: I was looking at the wrong page. :)  All good, thanks Robson.